# Locale independent Windows Performance Counters on multiple server versions

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, performancecounter

I tried to read value of a `Performance counter` with code below:

```
(Get-Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time').CounterSamples[0].CookedValue;
```

This is a language dependent command, so tried to make this language independent with code below:

```
(Get-Counter '\238(_Total)\6').CounterSamples[0].CookedValue;
```

It is locale independent, but I found it isn't working on `Windows Server 2003` based systems, because this object wasn't defined yet in this version.
How could I make this working also on Server 2003?

Comment: What is the PowerShell version installed?

Comment: @autosvet : PowerShell 2.0, yes an ancient one.